# Compile error when packaging maven project

Tags: maven-3, m2eclipse, datanucleus, maven-war-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm using datanucleus/mongodb. I recently converted my dynamic web project to maven in Eclipse because I wanted to use the maven buildnumber plugin. However I am just trying to get it to work now in maven. I do not have issues getting my simple projects to compile and run with Eclipse.

My projects are divided into 3 - main, LibA, LibAA.

Main relies/uses stuff in LibA (or directly from LibAA as well) and LibA relies/uses stuff from LibAA. LibAA doesn't know of other projects.

Example:
LibAA - DObject data class file
LibA - DRemote inherits from DObject
Main - DStaff inherits from DObject

That's how I set the dependencies in Pom xml.

So the issue here is that whenever I tried mvn clean package/install in Main project, I always get symbol not found for the data classes files that inherits from LibAA.

Datanucleus query says DStaff has been renamed to QDStaff, then later further down the process, it says DObject could not be found. Is it because DObject has been internally renamed to QDObject as well, hence it is too late to find them?

2 questions.

1: why is my data files being renamed. I.e a Q character is prependded
2: why am I still getting the symbol not found error despite calling datanucleus enhancer and correctly setting the dependencies? I have no problems with standalone data class files but only those that inherits DObject is the LibAA project.

I seems to have been missing something..

Any insights is appreciated.

edit: added a example partial compile log (with most of the similar errors/log removed)

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ MyMainProject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 591 source files to /Users/rhs/gitnew/MyMainProject/MyMainProject/target/classes
DataNucleus : JDO Query - com.rhs.kms.data.DServerSettingRecord -> com.rhs.kms.data.QDServerSettingRecord
DataNucleus : JDO Query - com.rhs.kms.data.account.DStaffAccount -> com.rhs.kms.data.account.QDStaffAccount
DataNucleus : JDO Query - com.rhs.kms.data.DMenu -> com.rhs.kms.data.QDMenu
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/rhs/gitnew/MyMainProject/MyMainProject/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/rhs/data/account/QDStaffAccount.java:[6,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class QAuthAccount
  location: package com.rhslib.account
[ERROR] /Users/rhs/gitnew/MyMainProject/MyMainProject/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/rhs/data/QDTableOrderingSettings.java:[6,65] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class QDObject
  location: package com.rhslib.database
[INFO] 10 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.056 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-14T16:25:40+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/300M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project MyMainProject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/rhs/gitnew/MyMainProject/MyMainProject/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/rhs/data/account/QDStaffAccount.java:[6,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class QAuthAccount
[ERROR] location: package com.rhslib.account
[ERROR] /Users/rhs/gitnew/MyMainProject/MyMainProject/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/rhs/kms/data/QMenu.java:[6,47] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class QDObject
[ERROR] location: package com.rhslib.database
```

edit2: This is an example of a file where it broke (taken from target/generated-sources/annotations/*)

```
package com.rhs.data.ARM;

import javax.jdo.query.*;
import org.datanucleus.api.jdo.query.*;

public class QDAccountApp extends com.rhslib.database.QDObject //error starts from QDObject
```

To iterate, DAccountApp exists in the main project. Main project depends on a lib named KMSLib, and KMSLib depends on a project named RHSLib. I have tried making Main project depend directly with both projects but to no avail.

edit3: attached my pom.xml from my Main project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MainProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MainProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>MainProject</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <api>JDO</api>
                    <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
                    <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>false</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>KMSLib</groupId>
            <artifactId>KMSLib</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcabi-manifests</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>DN_M2_Repo</id>
            <name>DataNucleus Repository</name>
            <url>http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>DataNucleus_2</id>
            <url>http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

edit4: attached my .classpath file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.runtime.runtimeTarget/WildFly 8.x Runtime">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Nothing is "renamed". You put the DataNucleus annotation processor (datanucleus-jdo-query) in your classpath and it creates ADDITIONAL query classes for use with their typesafe query mechanism. If you don't want to use typesafe queries then don't put that jar in the classpath. More than that, no comment is possible since you provide inadequate info

Comment: and look in the Q classes at the code and what those lines are and what is not found. The java code for them is under "target/generated-sources". aka debugging

Comment: i have added a partial compile log, and from your input, I've looked at http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/jdoql_typesafe.html. As you mentioned it doesn't seems to be the typesafe issue. The weird thing is that it works (as in it compiles and run without issue) directly in Eclipse. Edit: I'll take a second look at the code again

Comment: As you suggested, I've looked inside the target/generated-sources/annotations. I don't suppose there's an issue with the following code, right?
`package com.rhs.data.ARM;

import javax.jdo.query.*;
import org.datanucleus.api.jdo.query.*;

public class QDAccountApp extends com.rhslib.database.QDObject //error starts from QDObject` Main project depends on a project which depends on RHSLib project

Comment: if its in the classpath...

Comment: Added .classpath, I don't think there is any issue though... but I could be wrong since I'm still new to this.

Comment: I think I've solved it. It was a rookie mistake. I had to install the 2 dependent projects in the local repository first, which I didn't, since I thought it would be automatic. Now I have another issue but I'll open a separate question for it. Thank you for your help!